# AJAX/PYTHON : how to send json value to server

Tags: python, ajax

I am a new to Ajax/Python, I don't know how to POST a json value to my python server.

Python code:

```
@app.route('/ajouterContact', methods = ['POST'])

    def ajouterContact():
        data = json.loads(request.data)
        #nom = request.form['nomContact'];
        contact.append(data)
        ajouter.make_response(json.dumps(contact), 201)
        ajouter.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

JS code

```
$('#buttonAjouter').click(function() {
    var nom = 'Tom';
    var myObj = new Object();
    myObj.nom = nom;
    var jsonText =  JSON.stringify(myObj);

    var i = 0;
    $.ajax({
            url: '/ajouterContact',
            data: jsonText,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
});
```

I am getting this error on server side :

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

If anyone can help me on this..
Thank you!

Comment: If you put `print(request.data)` at the top of that Python function, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the contentType in your ajax request:

```
contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
```

Then in your server try to debug something like this:

```
request.json
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that was it :)